# Stenciljs: How to fix polyfills issue for Edge

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, polyfills, stenciljs

I just start using Stenciljs. I have polyfills related question.

Code below works at Chrome but it does not work on on Edge or IE11 browser which are two browsers that I need polyfills.

```
  <script type="module">

    import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'https://unpkg.com/<my-component>/loader/index.mjs';

    applyPolyfills().then(() => {

      defineCustomElements(window);

    });

  </script>
```

I am using

```
"@stencil/core": "^1.0.7"
```

Does anyone know how to make polyfills work?

Thanks.

Comment: Which versions of Microsoft Edge are you using? From the document, it supports Microsoft Edge 16+. Besides, you could check [this article](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil) to add the polyfills.

Comment: I am using 
Microsoft Edge 44.17
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18

Above code also does not work in IE11

Comment: I am following the code inside of Stencil doc (https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript ) but not sure why it is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following command to run the Stenciljs application:

Enabling ES5 builds during development:
    `npm run dev --es5`

For stencil-component-starter, use:
    `npm start --es5`

Enabling full production builds during development:
    `npm run dev --prod`

For stencil-component-starter, use:
    `npm start --prod`

If still not working, add the following tag in the header of the index.html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```